# Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars error message

Tags: python

This is my python code and I keep getting an error but do not know what I can do to fix it.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


xx = np.linspace(0, 1, 512)

for n in ([4, 8, 16]):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
    y = math.sin(2 * math.pi * x)
    yy = lagrange(x, y, xx)
    plt.plot(xx, yy)
end  
plt.legend(('n=4'), ('n=8'), ('n=16'))
plt.title('Plot of y=sin(2*pi*x)')
plt.figure()
xx = np.linspace(0, 1, 512)
```

This is the error.

```
  y = math.sin(2 * math.pi * x)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: replace `math.sin` with `np.sin`

Comment: Tip: your code will be unhappy with a couple other things. 1) legend requires an array: Try this: `plt.legend(['n=4', 'n=8', 'n=16'])`.   2) lagrange only takes 2 inputs not three